# Stacked barplot incorrect category labels

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

The hover labels show the labels correctly, but I am not able to get the correct category labels under my bars.

[image]

Here is the working example:

```
library(highcharter)
A <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
                y=c(0.7,0.8,0.7,0.3,0.2,0.3),
                group=factor(c("A","A","A","B","B","B")),
                cluster=c("C1","C1","C2","C1","C1","C2"),
                name=c("John","Sally","Ed","John","Sally","Ed"),
                stringsAsFactors=F)

A %>%
hchart(.,"column",hcaes(x="x",y="y",group="group")) %>%
hc_xAxis(title=list(text=NULL),allowDecimals=FALSE,categories=A$name[1:3]) %>%
hc_plotOptions(column=list(animation=FALSE,stacking="normal"))
```

I have tried setting `categories=A$name` in case it needs six values, but that doesn't work. I have tried changing some of the x-axis options (`startonTick`,`minPadding`,`min`,`max`), but doesn't seem to make it work.

I am using variable 'x' on the x-axis rather than variable 'names' to retain the specific order, else it sorts alphabetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has to do with the x axis being numeric. Two ways to get you what you want.

First, I'm assigning `x` to `name`

```
A %>%
  hchart(.,"column",hcaes(x="name",y="y",group="group")) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column=list(animation=FALSE,stacking="normal"))
```

Other way is to declare `A$x` a factor

```
A %>%
  dplyr::mutate(x = as.factor(x)) %>%
  hchart(.,"column",hcaes(x="x",y="y",group="group")) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title=list(text=NULL),allowDecimals=FALSE,categories=A$name[1:3]) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column=list(animation=FALSE,stacking="normal"))
```

Comment: In my real data with a few hundred samples, the first solution is causing stability issues. Bars disappear and so on. Not sure what's going on. The second solution seems to work. I had to change a few things. I guess you mean `"x"` instead of `"name"`. And then adding `hc_xAxis(categories=A$name)`.

Comment: Right you are, thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit my response to reflect that